# Transforming equations that are rational to quadratics and finding the roots

Tags: proof-verification, quadratics, rational-numbers, least-common-multiple

So I have this equation $$\frac1x - \frac{x}6 = \frac23$$

from what I learned and what I need to do, apparently I need to find the LCM of the $3$ denominators which I've thought up of $6x$ then if I multiply it to every term:

$$6x\left(\frac1x\right) - 6x\left(\frac{x}6\right) = 6x\left(\frac23\right)$$

then I cancel the factors(?)

$$6\bcancel{x}\left(\frac1{\bcancel{x}}\right) - \bcancel{6}x\left(\frac{x}{\bcancel6}\right) = (\bcancel3)(2)x\left(\frac2{\bcancel3}\right)$$

that leaves:

$$6(1) - x(x) = 2x(2)$$

simplify:

$$-x^2 -4x + 6 = 0$$

then I multiply everything to $-1$ to remove the negative on **A**

$$x^2 + 4x - 6 = 0$$

I do not believe this is the correct way to do it so can you guys spot anything that might be wrong in my end?

Comment: Why do you believe that your method is incorrect?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @iamwhoiam after using multiple online algebra math calculators I found my roots rather different

Comment: You can verify with WolframAlpha that the roots of the two equations are identical: [solve 1/x - x/6 = 2/3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201%2Fx%20-%20x%2F6%20%3D%202%2F3), [solve x^2 + 4x - 6 = 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E2%2B4x-6%3D0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiplying your equation by $6x$ we get
$6-x^2=4x$ or $$0=x^2+4x-6$$ and it must be $x\ne 0$

Comment: Is my method still correct? the fact that I cancel factors of 6x?

Comment: yes your method is correct